# Garbage value returned for some threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am rather facing a strange problem. This is not crucial for my work but I still want to understand this behavior. I am running three tasks in the order of their priority. I am calling one function from all of these threads with different arguments. For the highest priority thread (l3_thread) I get the right value for int J, but for other threads with low priority (l2_thread), I see garbage value for J. What is the concept that is at play here ?

Code:

```
int p_task(int limit1, int limit2, int sleep_time, int prio){

    int i, j;
    for(i=limit1; i<=limit2; i++)
    {
        j=j+1;
        printf("J = %d \n", j);
    }
    return 0;
}

void *l3_thread(void *arg){

    /*call to p_task*/
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *l2_thread(void *arg){

    /*call to p_task*/
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: You didn't initialize `j`. Compile with warnings enabled (e.g. use the `-Wall` option with gcc) and the compiler should warn you when the code has an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > I see garbage value for J...

This is because the variable `j` in the function `p_task()` is not initialized.

```
int i, j;
for(i=limit1; i<=limit2; i++)
{
    j=j+1;   //j is not initialized and used
```

If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is **indeterminate**.
*[C Standards#6.7.9p10]*